# Build a survey system on top of google forms

Tags: php, wordpress, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, survey

We built a survey tool on top of google forms using wordpress.

Simply, you create a google form, create a private open link, put into a wordpress backend page, then the system processes the module server side and generates the necessary html file. When the user fills the form and sent it, via ajax the server use zend gdata to write the results on the spreadsheet connected to the form et voilat.

But this system is limited, also because google form is quite limited. We want to improve it.
That's why I'm asking your opinions to upgrade the system to have some more features:

- We want to be able to keep the form open so that users can fill it in more than one occasion. theoretically then, we need to know which user the spreadsheet rows are connected to. This could be done by saving some sort of ID key to recognize the user, but then we don't know how to refill the fields in the form, since the spreadsheet created from the forms don't retain any sort of key to connect columns and form field.
- We need more field types! like a file upload field that put the uploaded file in a specific gdrive folder.
- We need to see the data for the single entry while google gives you only the whole spreadsheet that's quite hard to read.

It's not an easy task! Which solutions should we use to solve these problems?

Many thanks!

UPGRADE:

We decided to go by using a mix of google forms, google fusion tables, google charts via api access. Here's the simplified algorithm:

1. The admin user create his form via google forms and save the url. To have more field type, user can put a tag in the field comment, eg [file] for, well, files upload.
2. The url is put into an admin page of our system. The page fetch the content of the form page and extrapolate into an array, for every field, the title, the ID, the type and the comment; if there's some tag in the comment, this become the field type.
3. Using this data, system create if not existing a folder with a fusion table inside. if file fields are present, another subfolder is generated. Addresses of these folders and files is saved.
4. Using the array data, in the fusion table a column is created for each of the array fields, with a column title of this sort "[field_ID field_type]field_title", plus a column for the end user ID.
5. The admin user, can more over open or close the form.
6. When a user goes to the form page, the array is used to generate the form. If the system doesn't have in memory the user ID it means that the user has never filled up the form. Otherwise the system will use the user ID to fetch the data from the fusion table to populate the form.
7. When the user fills up the form, the entries are feed to the columns using the field ID as reference, plus the user ID. The user ID is also stored in the system the remember that the user already filled the form, as said in point 5. If files are uploaded, they are stored in a gdrive folder.
8. The admin user therefore can go to the admin page and see how many people has filled up the form, can ask for single user data, for summary data using google charts, can download a pdf of data from single user, every user, or summary.

Of course this is the idea, we have to build it. One first question is whether we should use javascript or php to communicate with google, so doing the processing on the client or server side...

Comment: Why not use an existing survey tool, there's a lot out there, is there a reason to avoid it?

Comment: can we see it, screen shots or a live site?

Comment: We are a non profit association, that's why we would like to avoid any paid services, and our need are pretty specific.
eddyparkinson no, we're still at the planning phase!

Comment: What are you actually asking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking about Javascript vs PHP, you should know that the Javascript API can't write to a Google Spreadsheet because of Cross-Domain Security issues.

PHP can as it is a server side language.  Zend Framework makes it easy to interact with Google Spreadsheets.  http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html

So go with PHP if that was your question.